# Local zetafunction of T-group and Lie-ring coincide

Tags: gr.group-theory, zeta-functions

Grunewald, Segal and Smith define in "Subgroups of finite index in nilpotent groups" a zetafunction associated to a finitely generated, torsion-free nilpotent group G by counting normal subgroups corresponding to their index: $$\zeta^\triangleleft_G(s)=\sum_{n} a_nn^{-s},$$
where $a_n=\{H\leq G: |G:H]=n\}$.
This zetafunction decomposes as an Euler product by counting normal subgroups of p-powered index.

For such a group of nilpotency class 2 they define a Lie-ring by $L=G/Z(G)\oplus Z(G)$ with $Z(G)$ the center of $G$. Then they remark that it is easy to see that for every prime $p$ the number of normal subgroups of $G$ of index $p^k$ and of ideals of $L$ of index $p^k$ coincide.
Christopher Voll states a similar result in "Zeta functions of groups and enumeration in Bruhat-Tits buildings" by considering $\mathfrak{L}=G/G'\oplus G'$ with $G'$ the commutator subgroup.

Can someone give me an idea how to prove one of these results?